# Trying to find my error solving an integral using tabular integration

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I have an integration problem.
$$\int \cos(8t) \cdot5e^{5t} dt$$
Integrating such a function by using the integration-by-parts method is complicated and messy. I wanted to use the tabular form, but for some reason, I am missing something, but I don't know what. Could anyone help me to point it out, please?

So far this is what I have:

| Sign | Derivatives | Integration | Product |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $+$ | $\cos(8t)$ | $$5e^{5t}$$ | $$\varnothing $$ |
| $-$ | $-8\sin(8t)$ | $$e^{5t}$$ | $$\cos(8t)e^{5t}$$ |
| $+$ | $-64\cos(8t)$ | $$\frac{e^{5t}}{5}$$ | $$\frac{8}{5}\sin(8t)e^{5t}$$ |
| $-$ | $512\sin(8t)$ | $$\frac{e^{5t}}{25}$$ | $$-\frac{64}{5}\int \cos(8t)e^{5t}$$ |
| $+$ | $4096\cos(8t)$ | $$\frac{e^{5t}}{125}$$ | ... |

\begin{align*}
5\int \cos(8t)e^{5t} dt &= \cos(8t)e^{5t}+\frac{8}{5}\sin(8t)e^{5t}-\frac{64}{5}\int \cos(8t)e^{5t}\\
&=\frac{5}{89}\left [ \cos(8t)e^{5t}+\frac{8}{5}\sin(8t)e^{5t} \right]\\
&=\frac{5\cos(8t)e^{5t}+8\sin(8t)e^{5t}}{89} 
\end{align*}

But this is not the correct answer. The correct answer is:
$$\frac{25\cos(8t)e^{5t}+40\sin(8t)e^{5t}}{89}$$
Please help me out here.

Comment: Only when one of the derivatives is zero do you get an answer solely using the downward slant products. If you stop at any boint before that, there is another integral to be added/subtracted namely that of a product of two terms across from each other. You also have a multiplier of $64/5$ which should be $64/25.$

Comment: @coffeemath, it wouldn't work out either, because if I move 64/25 to the left side, it would give me 189/25. As a result, it is even further away from the correct answer.

Comment: It can work, as in the answer below by user PrincessEev.

Comment: @coffeemath, Thank you, I see my issue now.

Comment: The only thing you actually did wrong in your solution was forgetting that you had factored out the 5 from the original integral, so what you solved for was $\int \cos(8t) \cdot e^{5t} dt$ instead of $\int \cos(8t) \cdot 5e^{5t} dt$; that's why your answer is off by a factor of 5.

Comment: @A.J. Thank you for pointing it out. I figured it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With tabular integration, products of diagonal entries lie outside of the integral, and the product of the entries in the final row of the completed table lies inside our integral. (In your calculation, it appears you have no such "horizontal product" and instead the integral at the end is simply the final diagonal product.)

The DI table I would get is

[image]

which gives the solution as follows (if we're careful to multiply the inside of the final integral by $5$ and divide on the outside by $5$ so we have the same integral as we start with):

$$\int 5e^{5t} \cos(8t) \, \mathrm{d} t = \color{blue}{e^{5t} \cos(8t) + \frac 8 5 e^{5t} \sin(8t)} \color{green}{ -\frac{64}{25} \int 5 e^{5t} \cos(8t) \, \mathrm{d}t}$$

Of course, if our original integral is $\mathcal{I}$, this amounts to the equation

$$5\mathcal{I} = e^{5t} \cos(8t) + \frac 8 5 e^{5t} \sin(8t) - \frac{64}{25} \mathcal{I}$$

and so, solving for $\mathcal{I}$

$$\mathcal{I} = \frac{25e^{5t}}{89} \left( \cos(8t) + \frac 8 5 \sin(8t) \right) + C$$

---

As a general look, the DI method would imply, for the below table,

[image]

that

$$\int a(x)f(x) \, \mathrm{d} x = \color{blue}{ a(x) \cdot g(x) - b(x) \cdot h(x)} \color{green}{ + \int c(x) \cdot h(x) \, \mathrm{d}x}$$

Notice that the items on the diagonals (marked in blue) are multiplied together and not integrated, but we have to tack on an integral: the integral of the product of the entries in the final row (not diagonally opposed, and marked in green).

Comment: Thank you so much. It helped me a lot.